# Site Configuration returns blank page

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, wsod

I have just updated the [Internationalization](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) and language_dropdown modules successfully after Drupal asked me to. Having done that, the `site configuration` when clicked every time, returns blank page. Sometimes when I click it twice, it returns a screen with a table of PHP errors of the the l10n update. This is frustrating. I know that this is regarding the update I made. But a bit of searching indicated that this is because l10n_update is still available in beta3 form.

Comment: when did you perform the update? I can see that there is a stable release of i18n (7.x-1.7) available now.

Comment: Friday. They only updated the i18n module but not the l10n module!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by troubleshooting the horrid [White Screen of Death](http://drupal.org/node/158043/).  Once you find the culprit module/file/function/setting this should be much easier to fix.

You may also want to scope out the [Language Dropdown bug list](http://drupal.org/project/issues/lang_dropdown?status=All&categories=bug), the [i10n_update bug list](http://drupal.org/project/issues/l10n_update?text=&status=All&priorities=All&categories=bug&version=All&component=All) and the [i18n bug list](http://drupal.org/project/issues/i18n?status=All&categories=bug).

If you will post back with details regarding the [WSoD](http://drupal.org/node/158043/) I'll do my best to update my answer.

Comment: Additionally, if the issue finds no mention in the issue queue, I recommend creating one ASAP.

Comment: well. Ok I try to reload the site configuration and Fatal Error table appeared. Fatal error: Maximum execution time 30 seconds in C:\wamp\www\drupal\sites\all\modules\l10n_update\l0n_update.inc on line 449.                                                          I have a screenshot if you like. How to upload it?

Comment: @Citricguy so ?? I have report the issue in l10n_update bug list http://drupal.org/node/1689392

Comment: When i disable the l10n_update module my admin/config works

Comment: Thats stupid but only by increasing the max_execution_time in the php.ini file to 240 worked. Now site Configuration loads.